# I read (it all/all of this story)?

Tags: idiomatic-language

Which is more idiomatic?

> I read (it all/all of this story), therefore I'm gonna talking about the whole story.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on context.  If you are already talking about the story, *I read it all* is great because "it" has already been defined.  If you have not previously been talking about the story, *I read all of this story* is better because you are presenting the object of the sentence.

Generally speaking, *it* works that way.  If someone already knows what *it* is due to context, it's absolutely fine and common use.  If not, presenting the sentence with the specific object is the way to go.  For example:

*A: Did you read the story?*

*B: Yes, I read all of it.*

But-

*A: I read all of the story last night.*